# How to safely open two large files (.rar and zip) from google drive on mac?

Tags: malware, virus, zip

I have two archived files which were shared with me on google drive. Im using a mac. Both are 9GB if I'm remembering correctly. The files are too large for google to scan for viruses, and too large to check with virus total. I believe they are safe, but I want to check both.

What is the best way to approach these big archived files? Should I use some kind of VM or sandbox? Is there an "unarchiver" app which might help scan the files?

Comment: You could download the files in a VM, extract them and run one of the [many scripts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck) which check file hashes with VirusTotal. Eventually you could [manually upload](https://support.virustotal.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002179065-Desktop-apps#mac-osx-uploader) those files with unknown hashes (mind by uploading files into VirusTotal you would be sharing them with lots of more or less legitimate researchers).